# Gtk.Application.Invoke not working

Tags: c#, gtk, cross-platform, monodevelop, gtk#

`Application.Invoke` occurs inside of a foreach loop, which I removed to save space.  When `bwSearchEngines` completes THEN the ui updates with the code inside of the `Invoke`.  How can this be corrected?  it needs to update everytime the invoke is called, which is called inside of a foreach loop that I removed.

When the button is pressed the button click event occurs, which starts the task.

`lblStatus` is a label on a statusbar, `tvResults` is a `TreeView`, and `OnBtnSearchClicked` is a button click event

To be clear, I am running Gnome 3.4.2 on Debian wheezy, **NOT Windows**. This is not a Windows app. I am using **MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2** and **Gtk# 2.12**

```
public void bwSearchEngines()
{
    //a couple foreach loops removed to save space
    Application.Invoke(delegate {
       lblStatus.Text = (engines.listSearchSesults.Count+1).ToString();
       tvResults.Model = lsTorrents;
    });
}    

protected void OnBtnSearchClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    lsTorrents.Clear(); //first remove data from TreeView before populating it
    btnSearch.Visible = false; //when a search is started disable search button

    Task.Factory.StartNew( () => {
    bwSearchEngines();
    }).ContinueWith(_ => btnSearch.Visible = true);
}
```

Comment: since **no one** wants to help i had to figure this out for myself. my solution is not what i wanted because it locks the ui! bwSearchEngines is called in the button click event and not in the started thread. so bwSearchEngines is called directly in the button event, which locks the ui until the function returns (function completes). this function is long running and shouldn't lock the ui BUT it does update like i wanted. Oh right after the Application.Invoke i had to add while(Application.EventsPending()) Application.RunIteration();

Comment: unfortunately this cannot work this way because bwSearchEngines will run really long, so blocking the ui is not an option but i must update the ui.  what i have presented so far need to work together

Answer (score 0):

since no one wants to help I had to figure this out for myself. My solution is not what I wanted because it locks the ui! `bwSearchEngines` is called in the button click event and not in the started thread. so `bwSearchEngines` is called directly in the button event, which locks the ui until the function returns (function completes). this function is long running and shouldn't lock the ui BUT it does update like i wanted. Oh right after the Application.Invoke i had to add `while(Application.EventsPending()) Application.RunIteration();`

unfortunately this cannot work this way because `bwSearchEngines` will run really long, so blocking the ui is not an option but i must update the ui. what i have presented so far need to work together